# Synchronisation for blocked threads

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I need a synchronisation point while all threads except the main thread are blocked (e.g. listening for a condition).

```
void *threads(void *arg){
while(true){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
    //check bus
    //do some work
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }   
}


int main(){

    for(int i=0;i<THREAD_NUM;i++){
    pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,threads,(void*)i);
    }

    //write to bus 
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    //write to bus
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    //write to bus
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
}
```

How would you do this?

Comment: Doesn't the main thread need to wait for all the other threads to finish the "check bus" operation before it starts the next "write to bus" operation?

Comment: Yes exactly, and even when the main thread waits until "check bus" and "do some work" is finished, it may still possible that the next broadcast signal comes too early to the threads.

Answer (score 0):

Use an integer, a mutex, and a condition variable. Set the integer to the number of threads you need to wait for. When a thread finishes, use the following logic:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Decrement the integer.
3. If the integer is zero, go to step 7
4. Block on the condition variable
5. Go to step 3
6. Broadcast the condition variable
7. Release the mutex

In code:

```
 pthread_mutex_lock (mutex);
 thread_count--;
 while (thread_count != 0)
     pthread_cond_wait (cond, mutex);
 pthread_cond_broadcast (cond);
 pthread_mutex_unlock (mutex);
```

Comment: the threads shall run in a loop, and only wake up when the condition is sent and then wait again.

Comment: @TomNeumeier Is that a problem? Just code what you need, using a mutex to protect shared state and a condition variable to block on.

Comment: yes, it is, I need to know when the thread is ready to recieve the broadcast signal, I don t see how I can achieve this with an integer variable.

Comment: @TomNeumeier I don't follow. Why do you think you need to know that? You just need a thread to block while the number of threads that haven't finished is greater than zero. (Which is precisely what the code I showed you does.) Do you need a way to pick one thread to start the next job? (If so, you can use the thread that decremented `thread_count` to zero.)

Comment: if i would send broadcast signals very frequently, the threads would not be ready to recieve the signal and do their job. The signal would come too early.

Comment: I m writing something like a bus and the threads are the snoopers, they listen to the bus, the do their job and listen again. And i want to know when they are ready again to recieve the next signal.

Comment: Then you can add `threads_waiting++;` right before `pthread_mutex_unlock` if you want. Just code what you need. Use the mutex to protect shared state.